does the quadruped robot suffer from Gimbal lock issue?
I am a student working on forward kinematics of a quadruped robot. I am confused whether we can use euler angle roll, pitch, yaw in  ZYZ Sequence for quadruped robot or not.
Does the angle vary till 90 degree in quadruped robot?

Have a look at this recent question and its answer.
A choice of angular representations is unrelated to a type of robot.
